# Android build flags?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm building an android app with 2 versions of paid and free. Basically I have a library project with all the logic and 2 skeleton projects for each version. Now I need some kind of build flags to distinguish between the versions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually do not need build flag for that. Here is how you can achieve this:

1. In your Library Project define resource: `<bool name="type.free">true</bool>`
2. In your application that is supposed to be free: `<bool name="type.free">true</bool>`
3. In your application that is supposed to be paid: `<bool name="type.free">false</bool>`

And then at any point in your Library Project you can check the value of Boolean resource and decide what you need to do. Of cource, you'll need access to `Context` object for this.